# Quantum Entanglement Particle Properties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have background in static/dynamic/thermodynamic physic. I am reading on quantum physics and quantum entanglement. Me and some of my colleagues were wondering on the properties that are shared between two entangled particles or structures (I read that they can do it on molecule size structures on Wikipedia). The exact question would be : is there energy level conservation between the two partciles, i.e. speed? Or is it just observable in a matter of particle spin?

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the *kind* of entanglement. You can entangle particle's momenta (as in the original EPR paper). But in the usual lab experiments spin is the entangled degree of freedom.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56700/50583). Entanglement is not specific to certain *"properties"*.

Comment: I see, is it possible to affect the momenta of a particle from the outside and see the impact in this relationship? A bold example would be if someone would add energy in the system (i.e. kick particle A), would this change be observable when looking at particle B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be no blanket answer about what properties are shared between two entangled particles because it depends entirely on the type of entanglement. Moreover, the entanglement of a single property does *not* necessitate the entanglement of the others (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166325/are-all-properties-entangled-when-one-property-is-entangled?rq=1)).

My understanding is that if particles A and B are say, spin-entangled, a kick applied to particle A would not be observable on particle B.

Comment: Thanks! The question you cited presents good articles if anyone else is interested.